# Does Uddhava belong to Yadu Dynasty and if so why did he not die because of sage's curse on the dynasty?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, bhagavata-purana

We know Uddhava is a dear associate of Krishna in Dwaraka. Who are the parents of Uddhava? Or atleast can we conclusively say that he belongs to Yadu dynasty? If he belonged to Yadu Dynasty, why didn't he die unlike other members of the dynasty because of the sage's curse?

Comment: yes, he was Yadava and a cousin of Krishna and he even looked like him, confusing Gopis of Vrindavan at one point that Krishna had returned.But Uddhava took message of Krishna from Dwaraka to Vrindavan. He is mentioned lot of times in Bhagwat Purana and Uddhava Geeta https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uddhava  http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/11/7

Comment: @Father i got this doubt because if uddhava indeed was a yadava, why did he not die because of the curse on Yadu dynasty. That's why i am especially looking to confirm whether he was a yadu. My opinion is also he is yadava, if that is the case, I have a profound philosophical point which I can make in future for a certain type of questions.

Comment: Because he had taken Sanayas after Krishna discoursed him Uddhava Geeta and told about future destruction of Dwaraka and Yadava clan. He went to Badrinath and took Diksha from Nar-Narayan sages and started meditating there. It is mentioned in Bhagwat Purana. Real Sanyasis are beyond curses and laws of Karmas

Comment: Gandhari, Dhritrashtra, Kunti etc., when got too old and took Sanyas, they also went to Uddhava's hermitage in Badrinath and Pandavas, Draupadi also left Hastinapur/Indraprasthata to Prakishit and went to Himalayas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Can we conclusively say that he belongs to Yadu dynasty?**

Yes, he belonged to Vṛṣṇi dynasty (subclan of Yadu dynasty), same as Krishna's dynasty. This is described in [SB 10.46.1](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/46/1). The commentary says:

> Śrī Hari-vaṁśa states that Uddhava is the son of Vasudeva’s brother Devabhāga: uddhavo devabhāgasya mahā-bhāgaḥ suto ’bhavat. In other words, he is a cousin-brother of Śrī Kṛṣṇa.

**If he belonged to Yadu Dynasty, why didn't he die unlike other members of the dynasty because of the sage's curse?**

As discussed in [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/23495/12304) post, all the members of Yadu dynasty didn't die:

1. The women, children and old men survived.
2. Also, the people who were not in Prabhash region survived: Krishna's great grand son Vajra (the son of Aniruddha), who was in Mathura survived.

As mentioned in [SB 11.30](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/11/30), Uddhava left for Badarikāśrama before the incident. Also, he was cousin of Krishna (whose age believed to be around 120 years at the time of that incident), his age must have been of an old man.